# How can i extract href link from webpage to text file

Tags: html, firefox, web, href

I have the webpage where there are 100 of href links.
Now i want those links in text file.

Its very time consuming to copy link one by one.

Is there any easy way to grab those links. I mean some greasemonkey script or firefox addon.

I tried using download managers but links gets changed but i want the original links as writeen in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use firefox addon LinkGopher to extract the links https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/link-gopher/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). If you have a handle on how to use regular expressions, you can do a large find a replace on an html file so that what you have left is only the urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bookmarklet.

- It gets all the hyperlinks on the web page and displays them in a new
  window.
- In new window you can copy all the links on clipboard and    save
  them.

---

```
javascript:

links_list = document.links;
links_list_length = links_list.length;

new_win = window.open();
new_win_doc = new_win.document;

new_win_doc.open();
new_win_doc.write(' <pre style="color: #111; font: 16px/1.82 Sans-serif;">');

for ( i = 0; i < links_list_length; i++ ) {
    new_win_doc.write( links_list[i] + '\n');
}

new_win_doc.write(' </pre> ');
new_win_doc.close();

/* for support: iAnuj.com */

void(0);
```

Comment: How can I copy all the links to the clipboard automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Using your WebBrowsers' Developer Tools (Crtl + Shift + I). Click on the Console and execute this code:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var myarray = []
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
var nametext = x[i].textContent;
var cleantext = nametext.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
var cleanlink = x[i].href;
myarray.push([cleantext,cleanlink]);
};
function make_table() {
    var table = '<table><thead><th>Name</th><th>Links</th></thead><tbody>';
   for (var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++) {
            table += '<tr><td>'+ myarray[i][0] + '</td><td>'+myarray[i][1]+'</td></tr>';
    };
 
    var w = window.open("");
w.document.write(table); 
}
make_table()
```

**Demo:**
[image]

**Results:**
[image]

REF: https://towardsdatascience.com/quickly-extract-all-links-from-a-web-page-using-javascript-and-the-browser-console-49bb6f48127b